# How to apply a regex to the content of a file on client side using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I have a form wherein a user comes and enters some data and uploads a file. I am trying to find out a way wherein can apply a regex to the content of the file and if it fails issue some kind of warning saying can`t upload the file coz the content in the file is not allowed for processing on the server side.

```
<div class="widget-body no-padding">

 <form action="exec.php" id="exec-python2"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="job_name" value="run_sql">
    <input type="hidden" name="job_type" value="sql">
    <input type="hidden" name="job_status" value="active">
<fieldset>
   <section>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
   </section>
   <div id="editor"></div>
</fieldset>
```

I tried something like this but this just shows encoded data

```
$("#button2").click(function() {

    if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        return;
    }   

    input = document.getElementById('file');

    if (!input) {
        alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    else if (!input.files) {
        alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
        alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");               
    }
    else {
        file = input.files[0];
        fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = receivedText;
        //fr.readAsText(file);
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        alert('a)');
    }

});

function receivedText() {  
    alert('hello');         
   //result = fr.result;
   alert(fr.result);
}
```

If I try to upload a file first on the server and use php to verify data and if it passes execute the contents of the file else send the error msg - > wouldn`t that be kind of slow .. Is there any way of looking at the contents of the file on client side and apply a regex to test the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `fr.readAsDataURL(file);`, this is converting your file to a *data URL* and hence "this just shows encoded data", the function you want is [`fr.readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsText), for example

```
function readTextFile(blob, callback, encoding) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.addEventListener('load', function () {callback(this.result);});
    if (encoding)
        fr.readAsText(blob, encoding);
    else
        fr.readAsText(blob);
}

// using it
readTextFile(input.files[0], function (text) {console.log(text);});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/69eYM/) (open your console)

---

You can make changes to the text in memory and you can cause the file to be "downloaded" again (see the [*download attribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download)), but you can't use *JavaScript* to save back to or overwrite the original file